# Case Implementation on Salesforce Communities

Tags: visualforce, bestpractice, case, community

I am currently working on an important project on Salesforce communities and one of the tabs that need to be accessible to external users is the cases object(my first crack at communities). I'm doing my due diligence by reading the Salesforce Case Implementation Guide [here](http://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_case_implementation_guide.pdf). I currently plan on using the out-of-the-box case layout for internal users and creating a visualforce page with limited number of fields for external users.
How have you implemented cases in the SF community and are there any gotchas I need to careful about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be worry about case implementation on communities. Most important thing to take care about visualforce implementation of cases are profile and permissions sets for the user. Which are wide from record level to object level. In communities startup, issue comes is few standard object tabs which were selected during setup are not visible to community user.

Keep aware of what profiles are eligible for communities login and is that profile has access to case object. Profile eligible for community are given during first community setup or can  be set up by going customise | communities | settings.

In my experience I came with issues with profile permissions otherwise all things are good.

In addition try to understand the logic written in apex classes which are created when you enable communities in organisation e.g. CommunitiesLandingController, CommunitiesLoginController etc. These classes are helpful in understanding the logic behind the scene how a user login and possibilities of customisations. Try to implement, if you face issue and unable to find workaround ask on salesforce stackexchange.

Comment: Hi Responsive. Like you said the profile and permission sets for the users are the most important things to take care of. At this point I have mapped out the eligible profiles and also used the communitieslogincontroller to redirect to my custom visualforce log in page. You said "you came up with issues with profile permissions" - can you expand on this a little bit and what resolutions you came up with. Thanks